# what is the meaning of providing : in python functions

Tags: python, hug

I am going through a python code which uses the hug framework as shown below:

```
@hug.post("/{scan_id}/files", versions=1,
          input_format=hug.input_format.multipart)
def add_files(request, scan_id: uuid):
    pass
```

Now the above code works fine if I do a curl request with multi part form with files.

Now I would like to reuse the same function `add_files` in a different place, but I noticed this part `scan_id: uuid`. I don't understand how an argument can be like this. **Can anyone provide any insight into this syntax?**

Comment: New feature of Python >= 3.6.

Comment: @juanpa Nope, function annotations have been there since 3.5. *Variable annotations* are new in 3.6.

Comment: My python version is 3.4.2

Comment: @deceze you are correct!